# SoapUI: mock service calling another webservice

Tags: soapui

I'm using SoapUI (v 4.5.1) to create a mock service for one of my webservices. When a request is received, the original service to be mocked returns an acknowledgement that the request has been received. It then calls a second webservice; it's this secondary behaviour that I'm finding difficult to replicate in my mock service. Can it be done?

I've also asked this question upon the SoapUI Community Board but have yet to receive a response.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: The original question wasn't phrased very well and so I have revised it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted by using a Groovy script in the mock service's AfterRequest action to mimic this behaviour.

Comment: I did find that running a test script in AfterRequest delays the synchronous response back, Why could this be happening? Isn't AfterRequest's script executed after the mock service response back? Do i have to explicitly execute something at Dispatch or at OnRequest in order to summit back the response before AfterRequest code being executed?

Comment: Please add groovy script or the whole method you used to get this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you created a mock service in a soapUI project.
Then you created a test suite & test case under the soapUI project.

The first step of the test case is calling your mock service. This service returns a validation that the request is received.

After the first step you want to call another service and you want to learn how to do this. If this is the case please follow below explaination. *(If not please give more information about the question.)*

You need to add a assertion to the first step (this assertion will validate the mock response returns the value that meets your expectation)
then, you should create another step. This step sould be a service request. Please notice that the mock service does not call the web service itself, you need to create another test step  for this purpose.

Hope this helps,